# how to edit simulink plutosdr qpsk example

Tags: matlab, simulink, telecommunication, software-defined-radio

I am working with this example from MathWorks: https://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/plutoradio/examples/qpsk-transmitter-with-adalm-pluto-radio-1.html

When i run the example it creates an `sdrqpsktx` variable in the matlab workspace

I want to change `sdrqpsktx.MessageBits` to something smaller.

When i run the following code in matlab:

```
a = sdrqpsktx.MessageBits(1:448);
sdrqpsktx.MessageBits = a;
```

I successfully change `sdrqpsktx.MessageBits` to `a`.

However when i run this in simulink `sdrqpsktx.MessageBits` changes back to its original size.

How do i permanently change `sdrqpsktx.MessageBits` and run the example with my changes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a model callback, probably a `StartFcn`, that is overwriting your changes to the variable every time you start the simulation.  You either need to delete or modify that code.

To see the code go to:
`File->Model Properties->Model Properties`, and select the `Callback` tab.

Any callback that is followed by a `*` has code in it.  Click on that callback to see the code.

See [Callbacks for Customized Models](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/using-callback-functions.html) for more detailed information.